# How to print a group of words with each words length in Haskell

Tags: haskell, input, split

I'm trying to print a group of words and each words length in Haskell. The words are within a .txt file so first I have to get the contents into Haskell and then I split them into single words, so I did this so far:

```
main =
       do
          textdat <- openFile "palindrom.txt" ReadMode
          inhalt <- hGetContents textdat
          winhalt <- return (words inhalt)
          print winhalt
          putStrLn "has the length "
          print (length winhalt)
```

palindrom.txt is the .txt file im taking the words from.  with openFile and hGetContents, I assigned the content of the .txt to "inhalt". "winhalt" is the content split up into words with the "words"-fuction.
Now im Getting this result:

```
"wordexample1""wordexample2""wordexample3"..."wordexample45"
has the length
45
```

(45 is the amount of words in the .txt file)

How can I split the sequence of words into single words so I can get and print the length of each word respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code (on its own source code):

```
main = do                                                                                                                                                                                               
    contents <- readFile "words.hs"
    print $ [(w, length w) | w <- words contents]
```

You get

```
[("main",4),("=",1),("do",2),("contents",8),("<-",2),("readFile",8),("\"words.hs\"",10),("print",5),("$",1),("[(w,",4),("length",6),("w)",2),("|",1),("w",1),("<-",2),("words",5),("contents]",9)]
```

Of course, you can format the output:

```
main = do  
    contents <- readFile "words.hs"
    putStr $ unlines [w ++ ": " ++ show (length w) | w <- words contents]
```